# t:jscookMenu current item

Tags: java, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I'm using `t:jscookMenu` in my JSF 2 application. I managed to make a functional menu so far, but how would I highlight the currently selected menu item for each page?

I'm not bound to Tomahawk, so if someone can propose a working alternative solution, I'll be happy too. The requirements I have for the menu are the following: side menu, sub items for some menue items, highlight while hovering over item, highlight currently selected item, dynamically created items by Java code.

Comment: take a look at the menu section of Primefaces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf

Comment: @Daniel I feared, that I'd receive links like that ;-) No honestly, I know of Primefaces, Richfaces, Icefaces and such, but even though they have mostly nice showcases, I could not find a menu which looked and behaved like I described above. But since the requirements are pretty basic, I assume that I'm only not using it correctly, that's why I'm looking for a more specific hint. It would be fine for me, if just basic and styled html like a list element did the job.